# How do I stop excel from rounding?

Tags: excel, formatting, rounding

I have an excel file that lists a number of items from amazon. It has the name hyperlinked, the quantity, the price, and the price per. I have an item that is $19.98 and comes in a quantity of 5. So the last column should say $3.99 but it just rounds to $4.00

I know its a small difference but there has to be a way to stop it from rounding to 4. When I add decimal places it just gives me $3.996 which is not what I want. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this--->  =ROUNDDOWN(19,98/5;2)

Comment: Thanks! What is the logic behind what's going on? It seems like for accounting, accuracy to the cent would be important. I've tried fiddling with the significant digits and that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: since 19.98 is not divided exactly with 5 you get 3.996 but 3.996 is money ,so you must have 2 demical digits.One choice is to round based on third demical digit.if it is >5 then rounds to the bigger number 4.If you use rounddown it rounds to 3.99

Comment: ohhh thank you so much it's been a while since I've had to remember basic rounding rules.